# How to extract elements of a list into a folder in Python

Tags: list, image, directory

I have a list of image objects. I want to build a folder comprising the images of this list, so that I can download the folder.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIL Image object has a [save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image.save) function that you can make use of.

Simply loop over each Image object and call the `save` function and provide it with the path of the image.

Example:

```py
for i, img in enumerate(list_of_imgs):
    img.save(f"{dir}/{i}.jpg")
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I had attempted most of what you suggested, but {dir}/{i} stumped me.  It's clear now.